# C# conversion of date from string to date format

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have a problem with the DateTime.ParseExtract. The error is `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`.

trialDate in the sqlserver 2012 is define as folllow type=date and it is display in this format
MM/dd/yyyy.  I guess it is the default for sqlserver.  I don't know how and where to change it to
dd/MM/yyyy or dd-MM-yyyy.

When I display the date in the listview I did this (put a mask):
    '

Here is the C# code-behind

```
    string sTrialDate = "";
    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
    {
       CheckBox MyCheckBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("MyCheckBox");
       if (MyCheckBox.Checked) 

       {
           Label myTrialDate = (Label)item.FindControl("trialDatelbl");
           sTrialDate = myTrialDate.Text;
       }
    }
```

The problem is the DATETIME.ParseExtract, here is what I tried so far:

```
   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("sTrialDate", "MM/dd/yyyy",   
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);    <=== not working

   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("sTrialDate", "dd/MM/yyyy",   
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);    <=== not working

   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("sTrialDate", "dd/MM/yyyy ",   
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);    <=== not working

   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString["sTrialDate"], "dd/MM/yyyy", null);              
                                                                                <==not working
```

Comment: `"sDateRdv"` doesn't look like a date to me.

Comment: I change it sorry it should be sTrialDate

Comment: `"sTrialDate"` doesn't look like a date either!

Comment: Voting to close as this is a simple typo by using a string literal instead of the variable name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be misusing `ParseExact`. You are doing:

```
ParseExact("sDateRdv", "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Which is trying to parse the string `sDateRdv` as a date and obviously failing. If `sDateRdv` is a variable containing your date then you should use:

```
ParseExact(sDateRdv, "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

In your last example you should check what the value of `Request.QueryString["sTrialDate"]` is. Is it a valid date string?

Lastly you talk about a date in sqlserver and how to change its representation. The answer is you don't really. A date is a date and is independant of how it is displayed. When you look at it it will be converted to a human readable string (because that's all we read) but that doesn't represent how it is stored. You would treat it as a date the whole way (so get it from the database into your C# code as a `DateTime`) and you only ever convert it to a string for display or maybe some kinds of serialisation (eg XML).

Comment: same error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime with DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(sTrialDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);   OR  DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(sTrialDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  The format of the string is dd-MM-YYYY

Comment: if the format of the string is `dd-MM-YYYY` then why not just change your date format to that? If the format you provide and the format the string is in differ then there will of course be an error. I'm not really sure what you are asking here...

Comment: As my database format is type DATE do we have any option to change the DATETIME to DATE ?   doesn't seem to have a DATE format in C#.  I guess I will have to drop the TIME if I want to compare with the DATE format of SQL which doesn't have the time ?

Comment: @user3127986, No. Per [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx), `date`, `datetime`, `datetime2`, and `smalldatetime` database column types all map to `DateTime` type in .Net Framework

Comment: If you have a date (no time) in SQL then in C# it will become a DateTime with the time set to `00:00`. If you want to compare this with something that has a time then just use the `Date` property of `DateTime`. eg `PureDate==DateWithTime.Date`. I'm not sure this is related to your question though is it?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you should not pass your variable in quotes:

```
   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sDateRdv, "MM/dd/yyyy",   
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 

   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sDateRdv, "dd/MM/yyyy",   
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 

   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sDateRdv, "dd/MM/yyyy ",   
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You could also try this:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
dtfi.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
DateTime objDate = Convert.ToDateTime(someStringWithDate, dtfi)
```